# Using ByteArrayOutputStream class to display Excel file but post download the excel file does not show colors as per logic

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

My issue is that I am using ByteArrayOutputStream class to display excel file with data and retrieved using toByteArray()

**Issue**: After I download the Excel file, the cells stops displaying required color after certain cells and I am unable to understand where it went wrong.

Code being used:

```java
protected ByteArrayOutputStream createXLS(Map contextMap) throws FwkException {
    long compteurLigne = 0;
    // On cree un classeur
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    // Pour chaque poste, on cree une feuille
    // On cree une feuille
    HSSFSheet s = wb.createSheet();

    // Creation entete de la feuille
    creerEntete(wb, s, contextMap);

    setTableHead(wb, s, contextMap);

    List listePoste = (List) contextMap.get("list");

    for (Iterator ite = listePoste.iterator(); ite.hasNext();) {
        HypothesesCompararerOutillagePoste hypothesesCompararerOutillagePoste = (HypothesesCompararerOutillagePoste) ite.next();
        creerLigneMatrice(hypothesesCompararerOutillagePoste, s, wb);
        setTailleColonne(s);
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream dataOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        wb.write(dataOut);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new TechnicalException("Error while writing the output to de workbook", e);
    }

    return dataOut;
}
```

Main Logic for colour being displayed in Excel file(xls):

```java
private void setCsPplusOuMoinsOutillageColor(HSSFCellStyle csPplusOuMoinsOutillage, String plusOuMoinsOutillage) {
    if (plusOuMoinsOutillage != null) {
        if (plusOuMoinsOutillage.equals("-")) {
            csPplusOuMoinsOutillage.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            csPplusOuMoinsOutillage.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.RED.index);
        } else if (plusOuMoinsOutillage.equals("+")) {
            csPplusOuMoinsOutillage.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            csPplusOuMoinsOutillage.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.LIGHT_GREEN.index);
        } else {
            csPplusOuMoinsOutillage.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.NO_FILL);
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the code where data gets retrieved toByteArray():

```java
protected void doEoxExecute() throws FwkException {
    try {
        Map contextMap = (Map) getInput(IN_CONTEXT_MAP);

        String langue = (String) getInput(IN_LOCALE_LANGUAGE);
        String pays = (String) getInput(IN_LOCALE_COUNTRY);
        Collection<Object> listeMsg = (Collection) getInput(IN_LOGGER_MSG);

        if (listeMsg != null && !listeMsg.isEmpty()) {
            Iterator<Object> iter = listeMsg.iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                Object msg = iter.next();
                if (msg instanceof String)
                    batchlog.info((String) msg);
            }
        }

        locale = null;
        if (langue != null) {
            if (pays != null)
                locale = new Locale(langue, pays);
            else
                locale = new Locale(langue);
        } else
            locale = Locale.FRANCE;

        boolean inSec = Boolean.parseBoolean((String) getInput(IN_TIME_IN_SEC));
        EOXContext.setCtx(!inSec, locale);

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = createXLS(contextMap);

        byte[] xls = out.toByteArray();

        // si aucune donnee, on affiche un message a l'utilisateur
        if (xls == null) {
            batchlog.info(getMessage(broker, "commun.export.xls.aucuneDonnee", locale));
        } else {
            String repertoireTemporaire = EoxBatchService.getPropriete(FICHIER_PROPERTIES, "GenererXlsDocPoste.io.temp", null);
            if (repertoireTemporaire == null)
                repertoireTemporaire = EoxBatchService.getPropriete(EoxConstants.FICHIER_PROPRIETES_SERVEUR, "GenererXlsDocPoste.io.temp", null);

            if (repertoireTemporaire != null) {

                File repertoire = new File(repertoireTemporaire);
                File fichierXls = File.createTempFile("doc", ".xls", repertoire);

                if (logger.isInfoEnabled())
                    logger.info("creation fichier XLS : " + fichierXls.getAbsolutePath());

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fichierXls);
                fos.write(xls);
                fos.flush();

                fos.close();
```

Also I am attaching the output of the excel file which shows no colors after certain 35th cell:

[image]

Comment: Try flushing the stream before returning? Maybe closing of POI classes also required?

Comment: Are you creating all the Cell Styles up-front and re-using, or are you doing one per cell? Excel gets grumpy if you feed it too many styles... make sure you re-use them!

Comment: @Gagravarr  I tried both of your suggestions didn't worked out.
However I tried to create sample code to create Excel file and and then converting file to byteArray using ByteArrayOutputStream class & retrieved it using toByteArray() method. Idk whether it's correct or not but I think the data is not passing completely through FileInputStream which might cause issue to pass it into OutputStream and hence not being retrived completely & can be reason why the colors are missing from the excel file. Need your suggestion to this. Thanks in advance :D

Comment: @g00se Even I tried your suggestions as you mentioned in the comments it didn't worked out unfortunately. Any other suggestion? Looking to my above comments please? Thanks.

Comment: First try running it on another machine.

Comment: @g00se Thanks for quick response. I have checked with 2 team members and it's the same unfortunately. Everything except colour is reflecting on the downloaded excel file and same I have shared on the post as well.

Comment: You really need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)